# Show how Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and std dev $\sigma$ is constructed.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I am a computer science student, who has recently taken an interest in data science. I've been learning about Gaussian distributions, and I've read from the documentation of the numpy python package [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) that sampling from a Gaussian distribution parameterized by mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ is effectively the same as sampling from a "standard normal" distribution (mean 0, standard deviation 1), then multiplying the result by $\sigma$ and adding $\mu$. Can someone please provide a proof or explanation of why this is true? Please clarify any steps thaty may not be immediately obvious to a non-math student. Thanks

Comment: https://www.mpp.mpg.de/~caldwell/ss09/Lecture3.pdf

Comment: Essentially because (assuming they exist) $E[aX+b]=aE[X]+b$ and $Var(aX+b)=a^2Var(X)$ so $\sqrt{Var(aX+b)}=a\sqrt{Var(X)}$

Answer (score 1):

Special about normal distribution is: if $Y$ has normal distribution and $Z:=aY+b$ (where $a,b$ are constants and $a\neq0$) then also $Z$ has normal distribution.

---

If we look at non-degenerate cases (as we mostly do) then the standard deviation $\sigma$ is positive. If $X$ denotes a random variable then based on it we can define a new one: $$U:=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\tag1$$ The relation can also be expressed as: $$X=\sigma U+\mu\tag2$$

This works for all non-degenerate random variables that have a well defined standard deviation.

In the special case where $X$ has normal distribution we can apply what I wrote above the line to find that (1) implies that $U$ standard **normal** distribution.

Looking at (2) we see that any normal distributed $X$ can be written as a linear form of a standard normal distributed $U$.